# c++ overloaded member function not found in 'ShaderProgram

Tags: c++

What's wrong I'm doing? Strange, because signature of constructor is the same. The compiler says:
'ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram(std::vector< int*, std::allocator< _Ty >>)': overloaded member function not found in 'ShaderProgram'. 
This error occures, when I use 3 files with code(below), but when I put this code in 1 file(main cpp) - it works

```
//main.cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "ShaderHelpers.h"


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    int* a = new int(5);
    int* b = new int(7);
    ShaderProgram *sp = new ShaderProgram(std::vector<int*>{ a, b}); 
    return 0;
}
================================================================
//shader.cpp
#include "ShaderHelpers.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector> 
#include <string>

ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram() { }

ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram(std::vector<int*> shaders)
{
    Shaders = shaders;  
    for each (int* i in shaders)
    {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}

ShaderProgram::~ShaderProgram()
{
    std::cout << "delete";
}


===============================================================
//ShaderHelper.h
#pragma once    
#include <string>


class ShaderProgram
{
public:
    std::vector<int*> Shaders;
    ShaderProgram(std::vector<int*> shaders); 
    ~ShaderProgram();

private:
    ShaderProgram();

};
```

Comment: Reduce your code to a minimal example (remove everything non-essential) that we can copy/paste. Your code seems correct, so probably the issue lays somewhere else.

Comment: Here is simplified version of program, the error is still there

Comment: Nope, this doesn't reproduce the bug. Are you sure you're doing a fresh build? You don't have out-of-date headers?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh wow, had no idea such Microsoft is up to pythonizing C++ ;) Nice find! Removed my answer as it doesn't reproduce OP bug, the error probably lies in some other piece of code. `%s/lays/lies` in my first comment, as we're not eating [this](http://www.fritolay.com/snacks/product-page/lays).

Comment: @vsoftco: Ahem pretty sure you mean Walkers ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm still in North America ;) Had no idea they immigrate to UK though (or maybe that's where they came from?!) Again [Wikipedia saves the day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lay%27s) :))

Comment: It should be fine. http://rextester.com/UQRCI10670

Comment: The project is 100% fresh. I created new project, copied code, built solution, but error is still there

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Now regarding C++, wth MS implemented an extension which (IMO) looks worse than the standard? Or was this before C++11?

Comment: @AlexanderPidoprigora Try putting everything in one singe file. Make sure it compiles. Then split it in multiple files, and make sure you add them to your project. The code [seems correct](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c418feb9afeb5df3) (you can see that an online compiler compiles it).

Comment: @vsoftco, I put all code in one file, and it works, but when it's in 3 files, I'm getting this error

Comment: @vsoftco It  was from before C++11. So if anything, you should blame the C++11 committee for making their syntax incompatible with MSVC, not blame Microsoft for making it incompatible with C++11. (Post-C++11 MSVC supports both, of course)

Comment: @immibis No, I'm not blaming provided this was way before std C++11. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add

```
# include <vector>
```

into the ShaderHelper.h